# one icon in front of another, aligned to right of parent div

Tags: html, css

I can currently place 2 icons in front of one another, however with `position: fixed`, I cannot seem to get them justified to the right hand side of my parent `div`...

I have attempted using `right: 0`, but this seems to justify with respect to the screen rather than div itself. Is there something I'm missing?

```css
.settings,
.clear {
  position: fixed;
  // positioning to right?
  transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
```

```html
<!-- Just for material icon purposes -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet">

<div class="expandPanel" #panel [ngClass]="{expanded: isExpanded}" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: lightgrey;">
  <div class="expandButton" (click)="togglePanel()">
    <a class="material-icons clear" [ngClass]="{hide: isExpanded}">clear</a>
    <a class="material-icons settings" [ngClass]="{hide: !isExpanded}">settings</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First **position fixed** property will position the element relative to view port.
So that is not what you are looking for. To align you child element relative to the parent element first give your parent **position relative** property and your child a **position absolute** property. I think this is what you want:

```css
.settings,
.clear {
  transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -moz-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -ms-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.expandPanel {
  position:relative;
}
.expandButton {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet">
<div class="expandPanel" #panel [ngClass]="{expanded: isExpanded}" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: lightgrey;">
  <div class="expandButton" (click)="togglePanel()">
    <a class="material-icons clear" [ngClass]="{hide: isExpanded}">clear</a>
    <a class="material-icons settings" [ngClass]="{hide: !isExpanded}">settings</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes sense... How would I alter this to say, if I had the button inside its own div (I have altered my code in the question).

Comment: You mean you want your 'expandButton' to be on left and your icons to be placed right relative to this button.

Comment: I'd like the button to be on the right hand side of the div that contains it. But the div can be placed anywhere in the page. - Just like in your updated code, but I still would like the icons to be overlapped

Comment: Yes that is what I have done in the above code. You can place the 'expandPanel' div any where you want.

Comment: When I click to `Run code snippet`, the icons are on the right yes, but they are not on top of each other :-(

Comment: Are you running my code snippet ? Cause My snippet doesn't have overlapping icons at all. Try running my snippet and update css code.

Comment: Could you help me have them overlapping?

Comment: I solved with making `.settings, .clear {position: relative}`